# Direct Access - managing computer clients with Remote Desktop

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, direct-access

I have a Direct Access configured, with IP-HTTPS , where all trafic is routing over IP-HTTPS. I have opened on the Firewall 443 port. My clients and servers doesn't have ipv6 public ip.

I have configured one of our station as management server. I have added station to management servers in DA wizard. On this amchine i have configured ISATAP. I have made GPO with ICMPv6 Firewall Rules with "Allow edge traversal" and ipv6 network scope for network remote.

Ping to clients from my station is succesfully.

Now i'm trying to enable Remote Desktop to those clients, so far without success. I have added to my gpo Firewall rules that permit traffic to port 3389 with "Allow edge traversal" and ipv6 network scope for network remote. So far with no luck.

Test-NetConnection on 3389 to clients stations return - failed.

Could you help me on this? I have no ideas what could be wrong in my config.

Comment: When you tried connecting via RDP, was there a user logged on to the remote device at the time?

Comment: Yes, client was logged on. But i did not get any windows with credentials. Am i missing something in configuration?